# How to resize an nvd3 chart when the window resizes?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I've created a population pyramid in nvd3, but it's not resizing as it's supposed to, and I cannot diagnose why. Here's a pen with the problematic code: http://codepen.io/laissezpasser/pen/qNrPXQ

For comparison, here's a working example of the responsiveness I'm trying to achieve in the pen above: Try [resizing one of the windowpanes in this pen: http://codepen.io/laissezpasser/pen/jrBGQG
For some reason, it seems to be ignoring the following code:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just simply broken, pay attention to the JavaScript console, it would have told you your errors...

```
// why is this line here, you've already set the data!
d3.select('#chart svg')
  .datum(data()) //<-- data is not defined
  .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

// why is this line here, interactiveLayer is not defined!
interactiveLayer.tooltip
  .headerFormatter(function(d, i) {
    return nv.models.axis().tickFormat(',')(d,i);
  })
```

Removing these offending lines, [fixes the issue](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWZAyw?editors=0010).